# php getdate returns date 2 hours off

Tags: php, getdate

I've got a pretty simple question. I send a date as millis created by javascript to a php site and use phps getdate to get information about the date in an associative array. My timezone is GMT+2, but I do not understand why date conversion using milliseconds should have any effect like this. Can someone please explain this to me?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying it's returning GMT time?

Comment: yup..I send a millisecond created by a client gmt+2, use getdate to read it and gets the previous day at 22:00, 2 hours back in time.

Comment: I think you just answered your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like PHP doesn't know what the timezone is supposed to be or the system timezone is not properly set. The simplest fix is to [set the timezone you want yourself](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) in the PHP code.

Comment: yes, I get how I can fix this by setting the timezone. The problem is I do not see how timezone should have anything to do with this. IF the date is one thing in one timezone, and I get the millis for that time to create a date in another timezone it should still be the same amount of millis since 1st of January 1970.

Comment: No, it won't be. 8:00 in one time zone is a different number of seconds from the epoch as 8:00 in a different time zone. (1st January 1970 means 00:00:00 UTC on 1/1/1970. It is a fixed reference point called the 'Epoch'.) It will be the same provided the time is correct, even if the timezone is off. But if the timezone is off but the local time is 'correct', then the system time is actually off.